# Cucumber: loop over only part of the Scenario

Tags: selenium, loops, cucumber, gherkin

is there any possibility to loop part of the scenario instead of all steps.
Below I have prepared an example, I want to login and click a list of links, but I want to execute the login-part only once. After logging the clicking part should be looped.

```
Scenario Outline
    Given I am on Homepage
    When I enter Email and Password and press send
    And I am logged in
    *And I click the link <link>
    Examples:
      | link1 |
      | link2 |
      | link3 |
      | link4 |*
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split your scenario in that case.  Make the login as a scenario, do not close your driver in between scenarios.  Now make the I click the link as a scenario outline in the same feature file.